# prevent inserting 0 values in table column using mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have table in which i am just inserting values coming from third party API. The value are integer sometimes i get 0 value from api and sometime i get value instead of 0. so i dont want to insert **0 value** in my table column only want to insert **value** instead of 0 using mysql.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_stockcompdata  
        (sto_name,sto_symbol,sto_closeprice,sto_openprice,
        sto_highprice,sto_lowprice,sto_difprice,sto_perchange,
        sto_keyvalue,sto_starttime) 
VALUES (Param2,Param4,Param3,Param5,
        Param6,Param7,Param8,param9,
        param10,NOW());
```

this is my insert query  where param are the variable which hold value in my controller

Comment: If any of param2-param10 are 0 you want to reject the whole insert?

Comment: This is better handled in the script that calls the INSERT, rather than in MySQL. You could create a trigger that prevents the insert but this logic would be separated from the rest of your application making the business logic "invisible".

Comment: no only param2,param3,param4 have 0 values then dont want to insert 0 but hold previous value

Comment: What previous value, you are doing an INSERT! Do you mean you want to do an UPDATE if the value is Zero

Comment: This question would benefit from the inclusion of sample data , the insert process and expected outcome as text

Comment: ^^^ Among other things :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: RiggsFolly i want to insert non zero value if 0 is coming then i want to retain the previous inserted value of that particular column

Comment: You should read up INSERT..on duplicate key. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.htmlcome back once you have done and read how to ask.

Comment: @P.Salmon pls read my query that 's not about duplicate values

Comment: Oh yeas it is..Prove otherwise by providing sample data and expected outcome (as previous.) AND update on duplicate key is not about duplicate values..

Comment: _ i want to retain the previous inserted value of that particular column_ Then you are going to have to look for the zero values in the inputs and then do a select of the previous row to get the previosu values

Comment: @RiggsFolly i want to retain the previous inserted value of that particular column if value coming from API is 0 otherwise insert new value which is coming from API